# selecting rows in numpy ndarray based on the value of two columns

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a big `np.ndarray (3600000,3)`, the `HUE`, the `VALUE`, and an associated `CLASS` number. For each pairs of `HUE` and `VALUE` I would like to find, using this array the corresponding `Class` number. I'm a very beginner in Python and have a hard time doing it. Do you know a way to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I assume your array looks like:

```
       |(HUE)(VALUE)(CLASS)
row/col|   0     1     2
-------+-----------------
0      |   0     1     2
1      |   3     4     5
2      |   6     7     8
.      |   .     .     .
.      |   .     .     .
3599999|   .     .     .
```

And here is the sample code. For simplicity I changed the size 3600000 to  5.

```
a = np.array(xrange(5 * 3))
a.shape = (5, 3)
```

Now array `a` look like this:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14]])
```

If you want row with `HUE=9`, do like this:

```
a[np.where(a[:,0] == 9)]
#array([[ 9, 10, 11]])
```

If you want row with `VALUE=4`, do like this:

```
a[np.where(a[:,1] == 4)]
#array([[3, 4, 5]])
```

If you want row with `HUE=0` and `VALUE=1`, do like this:

```
a[np.where((a[:,0] == 0) * (a[:,1] == 1))]
#array([[0, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: what about `HUE=1` or `VALUE=1`  ?

Answer (score 7):

Try this code:

```
 x[x[:, 2] == class_number[:, :2]
```

where `x` is `np.ndarray`

```
 x[:, 2] == class_number
```

contains `true/false` that means whether the last is `class_number` or not.

You need to take a look at: `Boolean indexing` in http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Indexing

Moved from comment.