# xtensor: Select rows with specific column values

Tags: c++, xtensor

I am playing around with `xtensor` and I just wanted to perform a simple operation to select rows with specific column values. Imagine I've the following array.

```
[ 
  [0, 1, 1, 3, 4 ]
  [0, 2, 1, 5, 6 ]
  [0, 3, 1, 3, 2 ]
  [0, 4, 1, 5, 7 ]
]
```

Now I want to select the rows where `col2` and `col4` has value 3. Which in this case is `row 3`.

```
  [0, 3, 1, 3, 2 ]
```

I want to achieve similar to what [this answer has achieved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359886/selecting-rows-in-numpy-ndarray-based-on-the-value-of-two-columns).

How can I achieve this in `xtensor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go is to slice with the columns you need, and then look where the condition is true for all columns.

For the latter an overload for `xt::all(...)` is seemingly not implemented (yet!), but we can use `xt::sum(..., axis)` to achieve the same:

```cpp
#include <xtensor/xtensor.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xview.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xio.hpp>

int main()
{
  xt::xtensor<int,2> a =
    {{0, 1, 1, 3, 4},
     {0, 2, 1, 5, 6},
     {0, 3, 1, 3, 2},
     {0, 4, 1, 5, 7}};

  auto test = xt::equal(xt::view(a, xt::all(), xt::keep(1, 3)), 3);
  auto n = xt::sum(test, 1);
  auto idx = xt::flatten_indices(xt::argwhere(xt::equal(n, 2)));

  auto b = xt::view(a, xt::keep(idx), xt::all());

  std::cout << b << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```